# .htpasswd - пароль для определенной ссылки с параметром

Tags: .htaccess, apache, сервер, веб-сервер

Можно ли защитить через `.htpasswd` доступ к определенной ссылке? Ссылка с параметром, то есть, такая должна быть доступна без пароля:

`site.ru/page/`

, а такая - только с паролем:

`site.ru/page/?param=value`

Чтобы пароль запрашивался при переходе по ссылке с определенным параметром и значением этого параметра.

Comment: apache 2.4 и настроить такое надо через .htaccess? Не через конфиг сервера?

Answer (score 0):

Для Apache 2.4 это можно сделать так (в конфиге виртуалхоста):

```
<Location /page>
  <If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /^param=value$/">
     AuthType basic
     AuthName "who are you?"
     AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
     Require valid-user
  </If>
</Location>
```